# use of generic types in dotnetcore

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I'm trying to do a method with a generic return type.
[image]

I have the using System.Collections.Generic; but it still doesn't seem to find the generic type T.

What else do i have to do to make it understand that T is a generic type?
[image]

Comment: Post your code as text, not screenshots. You also have to define either the containing class or the method as generic (`ResultService<T>` or `GetResult<T>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the function or the class to define the generic type

```
public static class ResultService<T>
```

or

```
public static T GetResult<T>(IActionResult result)
```